# Kv custom class in kivy jbhdfkjadkvbfjas

Tags: android, ios, kivy

i'm trying to create a kv that show 3 button with a custom class in a.kv file: But in the application there are 3 button with none color and text

SimpleKivy.kv:

```
<Buttond@Button>:
   color: 0,0,1,0

<Layoutt>:
   Buttond:
       size: 100, 100
       pos: 350,150
       text: "sdciao"
   Buttond:
       size: 100, 100
       pos: 250,150
       text: "sciao"
   Buttond:
       size: 100, 100
       pos: 100,150
       text: "dsciao"
```

here prova.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
class Layoutt(GridLayout):
class SimpleKivy(App):
     def build(self):
          return Layoutt()
 SimpleKivy().run()
```

EDIT:
  using color:0,0,1   text appers but it dont want chage the color

Comment: sorry, the problem was number used, 0,0,0,0  i think it's black, so it couldnt see on button(that has a black backgound)

Answer (score 1):

> color: 0,0,1,0

This is an rgba color, the a (alpha) is 0 so it's transparent and you see nothing.